# For HAML, need to use strict nesting level EVEN INSIDE COMMENTS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Such as the following HAML code for comments:

```
/ 
  We don't want to use

    foobar(something, something_else, ...)

  here
```

it will fail because HAML wants the indent level to be 2 spaces, and the `foobar` line is indented 4 spaces... come on... strict indentation... even in comments?  Isn't this a bug? (or a reasonable feature?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `:plain` plaintext filter, documented [here](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#plain-filter).

```
/ 
  :plain
    We don't want to use

      foobar(something, something_else, ...)

    here

-# this is a comment
  going to a second line
    indented extra on the third line
  and normally on the fourth
```

Which outputs this for me:

```
>haml --version
Haml/Sass 3.0.25 (Classy Cassidy)

>haml test.haml
<!--
  We don't want to use

    foobar(something, something_else, ...)

  here
-->
```

Comment: hm... kind of... not automatic... seems like need to "hack" it... also, some comments are better staying with the server and not public, such as "we better fix this or Jim is going to get xxx mad."

Comment: Ok, but your question was about HTML comments, using the `/` tag. Anyway, it seems to work fine with ruby comments too. I've updated my example for you.

Comment: oops... i forgot that `/` is actually converted to HTML comments... so the `-#` is for haml comments.

Comment: kind of easy to forget when in Sass, the `/*  */` is for staying in CSS and `//` is for removing in final CSS.

Comment: The reason `-#` is for comments is because `-` means "interpret the following text as ruby code" and `#` is for a ruby comment. Have I satisfactorily answered your question?